# How to label unique values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, label, pandas-groupby

I have dataset that contain 48000 rows as input text and answers. There are 89 unique values of answers. How I can make from text answers label answers for example 1 unique value equals to answer1, second to answer2 and so on up to answer 89.

---

```
> x               y                y_val
> hello     please push button 1   answer1
> what's up please push button 1   answer1
> be cool   please push button 1   answer1
>smth       please push button 1   answer1
>write num  please push button 1   answer1 
>hello      please push button 1   answer1
>what's up  please push button 1   answer1
>be cool        sure               answer2
>smth       sure                   answer2
>write num  sure                   answer2
>hello      sure                   answer2
> what's up perfect                answer3
> be cool   perfect                answer3
>smth       call me                answer89
>write num  call me                answer89
```

========================================================================

I want to change that "please push button 1" will become answer1,"sure" become answer2.I have 89 unique values so I need all of them to change that y_values become the columns that contains just answer1-answer89.

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe

Comment: x   y
hello  please push button 1
what's up please push button 1
be cool  please push button 1
smth   please push button 1
write num please push button 1 
hello  please push button 1
what's up please push button 1
be cool  sure 
smth   sure
write num sure
hello  sure
what's up perfect
be cool  perfect  
smth   call me
write num call me

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused, do you just want a recoded column appended to your dataframe that labels your 'y' column values as answer1-answer89?

If yes, this code will do that for you:

```
seen = set()
y_val = []
x = list(range(1,50))

for i in range(len(data)):
    if any((str(data.iloc[i,1]) == y) for y in seen):
        y_val.append(y_val[-1])
    else:
        y_val.append('answer'+str(x[0]))
        seen.add(str(data.iloc[i,1]))
        x.pop(0)

data['y_values'] = y_val
print(data)
```

This way of doing it assumes that the data is ordered alphabetically by column 'y' and that you're okay with the recoding following that ordering. Just replace 'data' with the name of your pandas dataset and make sure that the iloc is correct for your columns. I'm sure there's a more efficient or pythonic way to do it, but this is what I thought up.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I need to change the values of y to the form answer and unique number of that answer
> x               y                y_val
> hello     please push button 1   answer1
> what's up please push button 1   answer1
>smth       call me                answer89
>write num  call me                answer89

Comment: Oooooh so each pairing of x and y is equivalent to a unique answer1-89?

Comment: new=[]
    for answers in dataset.y:
        for i in range(0,len(dataset.y.unique())):
            if answers==dataset.y.unique()[i]:
                new.append("answer"+str(i))